# Intellij Idea Can't add Selenium sources.jar file

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, jar

I started to learn Selenium.
After creating the project I tried to add some jar files.
[image: JARs]

As you see all required jars were added. But

> ...sources.jar

looks like Empty Project. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this happening because ...source.jar file has a multiple files.

1. Click Libraries from Project Settings
2. +and add this .jar file here first.
   [image: Libraries]
3. When you added turn back to Modules
   [image: Modules]

After these steps "Empty  library" error is gone.

Comment: Yes, you should first define a global/project library. Then add it to the module dependencies. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-module-library .